# HTML Write side by side

Tags: html

I want to type words side by side.When I type words, they come one after the other.

Here's my problem:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6yZE.png)

I want to write this words side by side.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to achieve this.

First:

Use `inline-block` on children

```
<div>
  <p class="card" >privacy</p>
  <p class="card" >policy</p>
</div>
<style>
 .card {display: inline-block;}
</style>
```

Second:

Use `flex` on parent element

```
<div class="container">
  <p>privacy</p>
  <p>policy</p>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
     display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the HTML elements are in `display: block` , they appear one after another, this applies to all the elements
you can change this by changing the display property of the parent  like

```
   .dflex{
    display:flex
    }

    <div class="dflex">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    </div>
```

here all those children inside the parent will appear one after another